# Finding out where question views come from

Tags: discussion

Sometimes we get massive peaks in SO, such as this question: [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

At the time of writing, it has 201K views, so I'm guessing it was posted in some site such as reddit, and that's driving the traffic.

I'm simply very curious where that'd be, and was wondering if there's any way to find out in SO, or, since I'm already asking, if anyone knows of any tool that would do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find some sites that link to a specific URL, you can always just use Google search with the `link` search parameter, like so:

```
link: example.com
```

For example:

> `https://www.google.com/#q=link:+http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F6084360%2Fnode-js-as-a-simple-web-server`

Probably won't list all the sites that link to a particular URL, but you can possibly narrow down your search to see where a majority of the views may be coming from.

Comment: That's one neat trick. Thanks so much! Interesting username too :)

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing public and not much more available to moderators:

> [Is there any analytics information that moderators can access for individual questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-that-moderators-can-access-for-individual-que)

I don't know whether anything Google has would do the job.

Comment: Google (or anyone that crawls the web periodically) has the info, but as far as I know, their webmaster tools are only available to site owners who register for it, and then only for their own sites. I'll check and post if I figure out a way. Thanks!