# Does Stack Overflow store URL referral data anywhere publicly?

Tags: support, statistics, sharing

This morning I logged in to Stack Overflow to be greeted with a really pleasant surprise; one of my answers has today received 18 upvotes:

[image: Screen shot]

This almost definitely means that someone, somewhere on a popular resource has linked others to either the question or my answer.

I'd love to see where this spike in activity has come from so that I can potentially visit the source and read the article and/or comments surrounding this.

My first port of call was to go to Google and search within the last 24 hours. But what exactly do I search for?

The following, when searching over the past week (to broaden the results) all return nothing:

1. `"Make div 100% height of browser window"`, the name of the question.
2. `stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141`, the first part of the question's main URL.
3. `stackoverflow.com/q/1575141`, the first part of the question's *share* URL.
4. `stackoverflow.com/a/16837667`, the first part of my own answer's *share* URL.

I then thought I might have better luck looking at Stack Overflow's *shared a link...* badges to see if any users have shared links to that question recently, but alas, nothing. The last person to share the link to that question through the *share* URL was myself on Reddit - but considering that received no attention whatsoever, I'm going to guess this surge in upvotes wasn't down to my own advertising skills.

I imagine it may just be the case that the answer was linked to in a duplicate close reason on a recently popular question, but at any rate I'd love to be able to see how traffic finds its way to my answer.

Does Stack Overflow have any logs of this kind of data which would be publicly accessible if I wanted to see it?

Comment: That data is not publicly accessible, no.

Comment: Cross-meta dupe: [Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99042)

Comment: "This almost definitely means that someone, somewhere on a popular resource has linked others to either the question or my answer." Not necessarily. Sometimes a good number of people find your posts by lurking here, and if the posts are good that happens.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262131/finding-out-where-question-views-come-from

Comment: part of the source of traffic http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/2nlz2v/amazingly_new_easy_way_to_make_element_100_of/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stack Overflow may not be publicly accessible, but Google is (ish), and I think I have found the source!

By searching for your [linked answer URL in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1575141%2Fmake-div-100-height-of-browser-window%2F16837667&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) we come up with a few hits.

The question itself, this meta thread, and a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/saijo_george).

Given that Twitter is probably blocked for most of us, I went ahead and checked on my cell phone.

Sure enough, 14 hours ago, the Twitter user linked to your exact answer. The Twitter user appears to be human and have ~800 followers, so there's probably an Stack Overflow user in there somewhere. It's possible that the answer may also have been bumped up as a result of upvotes (I don't know how the tubes work), which may have resulted in additional upvotes from people on Stack Overflow who are not following the Twitter account.

Comment: That's very interesting. That tweet was indeed posted around the time the upvotes started coming in - so I imagine that was the cause. Not sure why I was unable to find that on Google just 2 hours ago mind you...

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I assume the webcrawler was extra-loaded on turkey and got stuck in a pipe somewhere.

Comment: Here is a direct link to the tweet : https://twitter.com/Saijo_George/status/538126620674904064

Comment: @Compass I was thinking that perhaps the actual question appeared as a 'Hot Network Question', which in-turn exposed the answer and received many upvotes?

Comment: @cybermonkey one likely caused the other. At this point, it's hard to tell. But a tweet from a web developer to a group of followers could have pushed it onto that list due to increased traffic.